# Change color when the button is active (WPF in MVVM architecture)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="English" Content="English" 
        Background="{Binding Button0}" Width="80" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" 
        Margin="8,15,162,21"/>     
<Button Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="China" Content="中国" 
        Background="{Binding Button1}" Width="80" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" 
        Margin="78,19,77,21" />
<Button Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="Tamil" Content="தமிழ்" 
        Background="{Binding Button2}" Width="80" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" 
        Margin="165,15,10,21" />
```

***I want to change the color of button when An active button. Please help me***
I want to change my button colors when one button clicked the color should be change as different from other buttons. and after clicking an another button the button clicked previously should be colored as normal an just clicked button should as mentioned.

Comment: Add more details to support your question. It's very vague.

Comment: @dhilmathy Sorry that's a mistake. Now is it ok?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of toggle. Which mean, only the clicked button should be in different color and others as normal?

Comment: @dhilmathy Yes Only the clicked button should be different color and others as normal.there is three buttons. all three buttons are same color(blue). when user click on 1st button it will change that button color as red. But when user click on second button, first button must turn into blue color and clicked button(2nd button) must turn in to red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `RadioButton` grouping.

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GroupToggleStyle" TargetType="RadioButton" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                         Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger.Setters>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LanguageGroup" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
                 CommandParameter="English" Content="English" Width="80" 
                 Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LanguageGroup" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
                 CommandParameter="China" Content="中国" Width="80" 
                 Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="LanguageGroup" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" 
                 CommandParameter="Tamil" Content="தமிழ்" Width="80" 
                 Style="{StaticResource GroupToggleStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: I need normal buttons. Instead radio Buttons

Comment: It's better to work with `RadioButton` for your case. Is there any specific reason you are looking for a `Button` instead of `RadioButton` ?

Comment: I am new to WPF. My sir told me to use buttons instead Radio buttons.(I think that is client requirement)

Comment: @HasithYoman A RadioButton is also a Button. And it can be styled to look exactly like the standard Button.

Comment: @clemens Can you show me output of that button

Comment: @HasithYoman i'd added the output of the solution provided above. As @clemens mentioned, it's actually a `Button`. The styling to `RadioButton` applied makes it to look like standard `Button`.

Comment: @dhilmathy when I added your code to xaml it show this error. **"The attachable property Resource was not found in type window"**.. How to fix that error

Comment: I believe you might be using `UserControl` then. If so, change `Window.Resources` to `UserControl.Resources`. If not, can you share your code; which can help to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @dhilmathy I tried your code but the out put is toggle button.

Comment: @dhilmathy you are amaizing. finaly I got a solution

Answer (score -2):

You could try to refer to the following code.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="50" Width="100" Content="Button1" Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="English">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton1Active}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Button Height="50" Width="100"   Content="Button2"  Command="{Binding LanguageChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="China">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsButton2Active}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSeaGreen" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ButtonCommand
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext=new ViewModel();
    }
  }
  public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    public ViewModel()
    {
      languageChangeCommand = new UICommand(OnClick);
    }
    private UICommand languageChangeCommand;
    public UICommand LanguageChangeCommand
    {
      get { return languageChangeCommand; }
    }
    private void OnClick(object parameter)
    {
      switch (parameter.ToString())
      {
        case "English":
          IsButton1Active = true;
          IsButton2Active = false;
          break;

        case "China":
          IsButton2Active = true;
          IsButton1Active = false;
          break;
      }
    }
    private bool isButton1Active;
    private bool isButton2Active;
    public bool IsButton1Active
    {
      get { return isButton1Active; }
      set { isButton1Active = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public bool IsButton2Active
    {
      get { return isButton2Active; }
      set { isButton2Active = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
  }
  public class UICommand : ICommand
  {
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    public UICommand(Action<object> onExecuteMethod, Func<bool> onCanExecuteMethod = null)
    {
      _execute = onExecuteMethod;
      _canExecute = onCanExecuteMethod;
    }
    public bool IsCanExecute { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
      add { if (_canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
      remove { if (_canExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      _execute(parameter);
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      IsCanExecute = (_canExecute == null || _canExecute());
      return IsCanExecute;
    }
    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
      CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And when there are 10 Buttons, you have 10 IsButtonXActive properties in your view model? A single string or integer or enum property would obviously be far better. There should also not be two DataTriggers on a single property - unless you are handling more than two states. Declare a Setter for the default Background and one in a DataTrigger for the "active" Background. And please avoid putting animated GIFs in your posts. That is just annoying.

Comment: I will revise and update gradually. Could you give some code as a hint?

Comment: Use a single enum property. If you do not know how to use that with a DataTrigger, you should probably not be writing answers to WPF questions at all.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST You are amaizing. But I need this one in MVVM architecture

Comment: Hi,@HasithYoman. It is a simple MVVM, you could combine it into your code.

Comment: @Clemens.I'll try to change it.

Comment: Hi @HuiLiu-MFST .. I code my project using MVVM architecture. So this one also I have to code it using that architecture. So can you please again share your code with me in MVVM architecture

Comment: @Clemens If you could changed it in MVVM architecture. Please share your code with me. Thank you

Comment: Hi,@HasithYoman.I did not use a MVVM framework,It can be seen as a native self-written MVVM.Which MVVM framework are you using？

Comment: @HasithYoman This is already MVVM, just a bad example of implementing a state in a view model. Use a single enum property instead of multiple boolean properties.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST I am use version 4.  If you can please help me

Comment: @Clemens Can you give me a good example in MVVM architecture